# Coloring twice in OpenGl es

Tags: colors, opengl-es, textures

i m doing color picking for my project, i m working with iphone sdk and my project substantially(for color picking part) load 3d models with texture, the "loader" own an array of objects, those objects are presented with drawView and are updated with redrawView. When i click with mouse on the iphone simulator i just call the method drwanWithOneUniqueColor
that should color each object in the array with one different color. 
The result with number of models 3 so with array model count = 3 is: on the view just 1 object with 1 color , in a different position where was the object( in front of the view ) and under 3 models with texture and the 2 and 3 model are not colored why?

THE OBJECT VIEW
and
THE LOADER AND REDER OBJECTS
http://pastebin.com/LHpmFAzn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i m working on and i m discovering that models was well colored but attached one on the other
in this way i could see just 1 of them. 
now i should resolve the question of translate in the right way the objects.